# How to call a function with function name reference to a string value in VB

Tags: vb6

I have this algorithm that I want to implement on VB6.

```
Sub Main()
dim stringVal1 as string, stringVal2 as string
dim getOne as boolean

stringVal1 = "FunctOne"
stringVal2 = "FunctTwo"

if getOne then
    'Call Function with function name assigned to stringVal1 ... how to call the function here?**
else
    'Call Function with function name assigned to stringVal1 ... how to call the function here?**
end if

End Sub


Function FunctOne()
   Msgbox "I'm function one"
End Function

Function FunctTwo()
   Msgbox "I'm function two"
End Function
```

Can this be done in VB6?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally, such code patterns point to errors in your software design.

In the rare cases where this is really needed, **`CallByName`** accomplishes this.

Example:

```
Call CallByName(Me, "NameOfFunction", vbMethod, arguments)
```

Comment: AFAIK it is the only way to do polymorphism in vb6

Comment: @Andrey: no, you’re quite wrong: VB6 knows interfaces (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581087). Furthermore, VB6 supports late binding out of the box so you can just call methods on polymorphic objects (but this no longer works with `Option Explicit`).

Comment: @Konrad +1 for your answer and your comment. A minor point though: late-binding still works with `Option Explicit`?

Comment: @MarkJ: Does it? It’s been too long since I last used VB6, apparently. :-(

Comment: @Konrad So refreshing to hear someone say that! Even as a joke

Comment: @Andrey maybe if you hate VB6 so much you shouldn't comment on VB6 questions

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you give more information about why you're needing to call functions by the string representation of their name. Could you not simply re-write your code like this:

```
If getOne Then 
    Call FuncOne()
Else 
    Call FuncTwo() 
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you don't want to actually dispatch based on Strings. This is error-prone (as you have to be really sure at run time that your String has the function name you want), and really unnecessary. The way to do this sort of thing where you want to be able to "pass in" the method that you want to use would be to use the polymorphism that VB has, and use a separate Class for each implementation.

In the Class Module that you use for your interface, say named `MyInterface`:

```
Public Sub DoStuff()
End Sub
```

Then, create two Class Modules, one for each possible implementation of the Interface:

In `MyClassOne`:

```
Implements MyInterface
Public Sub MyInterface_DoStuff()
    Msgbox "I'm function one"
End Sub
```

Then, in `MyClassTwo`, the same thing but with your other implementation:

```
Implements MyInterface
Public Sub MyInterface_DoStuff()
    Msgbox "I'm function two"
End Sub
```

To use it, you just need to pass in which implementation you want to use:

```
Private Sub UseInterface(WhichThingToUse as MyInterface)
  WhichThingToUse.DoStuff
End Sub
```

Rather than using a String variable to store which method to use, you need to instead store a `New MyClassOne` or a `New MyClassTwo`. You don't show how your `getOne` variable gets set, but whatever the logic is for it, you just need to change to store an instance of MyInterface instead, and just use that directly.

For further reading in the MSDN library:

- [How Visual Basic Provides Polymorphism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa241891%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)
- [Creating and Implementing an Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262286%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)
- [Creating Interfaces for Use With the Implements Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262287%28VS.60%29.aspx)
- [Implements Statement reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243384%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)