# Pass name procedure to another procedure in vb6

Tags: function, vb6

I need in VB6 something like this:

```
private sub function1 (a1 as integer, a2 as integer) as double
  'code of function1
end function

private sub function2 (b1 as integer, b2 as integer) as double
  'code of function2
end function

private sub function3 (kk as string) as string
  dim c1 as double
  dim c2, c3 as integer
  c1 = kk(c2,c3)
  ' In kk appear the name of function1 or function2
end function
```

This code is wrong. 
Pass a control name to another procedure, I read that is possible, 
But, is possible in vb6 that with a name function?

Thanks

Comment: Here is another question dealing with the same issue:   https://stackoverflow.com/q/2629807/5162073.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a function with function name reference to a string value in VB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629807/how-to-call-a-function-with-function-name-reference-to-a-string-value-in-vb)

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to call different code in different circumstances isn't to call methods based on a String. Generally, the way to do this sort of thing where you want to be able to "pass in" the method that you want to use would be to use the polymorphism that VB has, and use a separate Class for each implementation.

In the Class Module that you use for your interface, say named `MyInterface`:

```
Public Function DoStuff(a1 as Integer, a2 as Integer) As Double
End Function
```

Then, create two Class Modules, one for each possible implementation of the Interface:

In `MyClassA`:

```
Implements MyInterface
Public Function MyInterface_DoStuff(a1 as integer, a2 as integer) As Double
    'code of function 1
End Function
```

Then, in `MyClassB`, the same thing but with your other implementation:

```
Implements MyInterface
Public Function MyInterface_DoStuff(a1 as integer, a2 as integer) As Double
    'code of function 2
End Function
```

To use it, you need to have the caller pass in an instance that implements MyInterface:

```
Private Sub Function3 (kk as MyInterface)
  dim c1 as double
  dim c2, c3 as integer
  c1 = kk.DoStuff(c2,c3)
  ' In kk appear any instance of MyInterface that you want to use
End Sub
```

An example of calling Function3:

```
Dim kk as MyInterface
Set kk = New MyClassA
Function3 kk
```

For further reading in the MSDN library:

- [How Visual Basic Provides Polymorphism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa241891%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)
- [Creating and Implementing an Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262286%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)
- [Creating Interfaces for Use With the Implements Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262287%28VS.60%29.aspx)
- [Implements Statement reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243384%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)